# Google Application Script - onChange or OnEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google application script that changes a value in A1 in onLoad event in a spreadsheet. This triggers a cascade of changes. I would like to detect the event when let's say cell F200 is changed because of the edit to cell A1. How do I set up the triggers to detect this change?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

Answer (score 16):

An installable open trigger runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, or form that he or she has permission to edit.
An installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet.
An installable change trigger runs when a user modifies the structure of a spreadsheet itself — **for example, by adding a new sheet or removing a column.**
An installable form-submit trigger runs when a user responds to a form. There are two versions of the form-submit trigger, one for Google Forms itself and one for Sheets if the form submits to a spreadsheet.