# Behaviour of Edit OnChange triggers when used together

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I have a Google spreadsheet for which I have written a script which uses both `onEdit` and `onChange` triggers. I am trying to figure out the scenarios on which the events trigger. There are few scenarios like:

When I delete/add a value from/to an existing cell, I’m expecting the `onEdit` event to get triggered but instead sometimes `onChange` triggers even though the action is considered to be manipulation of an existing cell.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange

Similarly, when I delete a column, instead of `onChange`, `onEdit` event triggers.

Is there an order of priority based on which these triggers work when put together in a script?

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange) you provided pretty much says it all. This might be caused by the possibility that `onChange()` is triggered by `onEdit` or vice versa, also as on how I understand the definitions on the [Event docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change), the `Change` events is pretty much about the **whole** spreadsheet, while the `Edit` is/can be specific to a certain (range of) cell(s).

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234631/6124253) is very helpful, it might give you some ideas. Don't know if [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389875/google-application-script-onchange-or-onedit) could also help, but I think the answer here is quite definitive.