# Why do both onChange and onEdit triggers fire at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have now a spreadsheet where I want to:

- Track when someone CHANGES a value in a cell that already has a value
- Track when someone adds a NEW value in a cell that has no value
- Track when someone DELETES a value in a cell

Now when I test install-triggers and even onEdit() and onChange() I just don't get it that why both fires whenever I change a value or add new value on blank cell.

You can see my code here:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox('EDIT')
}
// trigger --> change
function onmychange(e){
 Browser.msgBox('CHANGE')
}
```

If I edit a cell with value and change it to something else, both get fired
If I write something in a new cell, both fired

My trigger: onmychange --> on spreadsheet --> on change

Why do both get fired?

Comment: There are 2 trigger type, (Simple)[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/] and (Installable)[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable].  Since there is not a Simple trigger for a Change event, you must have defined `onmychange()` as an Installable trigger.  Did you set both as an Edit trigger?  You want it to be a Change trigger.  onEdit() is a Simple trigger so you do not need to define that one in the Installable triggers location as the name of the function is enough to trigger it on edits.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389875/google-application-script-onchange-or-onedit for an explanation of trigger types

Comment: onmychange() is on change in triggers and onEdit i have nothing. still both fires and not just one.

When i change value in a col BOTH fires<br>
When i add value in blank col BOTH fires

Ive tried to trigger on change and edit in triggers, but i dont know why this happends, im aware of trigger types terrywb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change), the "on change" trigger includes EDIT among other kinds of changes:

> The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER)

If you wanted to not execute code when the change is an edit, use a condition such as

```
function onmychange(e) {
  if (e.changeType != "EDIT") {
    Browser.msgBox("Change that is not an edit");
  }
}
```

That said, all the actions you mentioned (CHANGES a value in a cell that already has a value, adds a NEW value in a cell that has no value, DELETES a value in a cell) are Edits, so `onEdit` is the only trigger you need.

If the goal is to find what kind of an edit was made, use `e.value` and `e.oldValue`. The former has some quirks when using simple trigger `onEdit(e)`:

1. If a user inputs "foo" directly (includes pasting from an external source): e.value is "foo"
2. If a user pastes "foo" that was copied from elsewhere in the sheet: e.value is `{}`, empty object.
3. If a user clears out the cell that had "foo" previously: e.value is the object `{"oldValue":"foo"}`

(If one uses an installable trigger running on edit, then in cases 2 and 3 there is no property "value" in the event object at all.)

In order to get around the aforementioned quirks, I use the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var newValue = (typeof e.value == "object" ? e.range.getValue() : e.value); 
  //
}
```

which makes sure that `newValue` has the new value that is now in the cell.

You may want to observe the behavior of triggers by using the following logging trigger:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```